# Change column layout for a div using jquery at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on integrating a web-based portal by a third party vendor.
It allows customization by providing javacript and CSS in one of its section which will include this provided javascript and CSS while loading webpages to show the customized effect.

One of the customization require hiding of a div (login-frm), and making another div wider. These div elements have column layout set, as follows:

```
 <div class="login-wc col-md-6"> </div>

 div class="login-frm col-md-6"> </div>
```

How can I change the `col-md-6` to `col-md-12` for the first div using javacript or jquery on page load?

Any help will be really appreciable.

Thank you,
Jaquen

Comment: Oh. I found other things about adding removing class, but i thought this could be something different. Being a newbie to JS/CSS, i wondered if there exists something different. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeClass` and `addClass` as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.login-wc').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-12');
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.login-wc').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-12');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-wc col-md-6">ABC </div>

<div class="login-frm col-md-6">CDE </div>
```